# Using @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation in spring data jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I try to use the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation. When doing this, I get an error - *attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property*.

The user is saved, but the address is not saved. I want to create a common primary key for the `User` and `Address` table. I found an example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one).

Please, tell me what I'm doing wrong, why doesn't this example work for me?

**https://github.com/mytestPercon/TestHiber**

**User.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "TestKeyJoin")
public class User implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;

   @Basic
   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
   private Address activated;

   // Getter and Setter ...
}
```

**Address.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Address", schema = "TestKeyJoin")
public class Address implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   @Basic
   @Column(name = "city")
   private String city;

   @OneToOne
   @MapsId
   @JoinColumn(name = "id")
   private User user;

   // Getter and Setter ...

}
```

**SaveController.java**

```java
@Controller
public class SaveController {

   @Autowired
   ServiceJpa serviceJpa;

   @GetMapping(value = "/saveUser")
   public String getJpa () {
      User user = new User();
      user.setId(1L);
      user.setName("Michael Joseph Jackson");
      serviceJpa.saveUser(user);

      Address address = new Address();
      address.setId(1L);
      address.setCity("Los Angeles");
      serviceJpa.saveActivated(address);

      return "/saveUser";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to correct your mapping in the following way:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "TestKeyJoin")
public class User implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private Address address;

   // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Address", schema = "TestKeyJoin")
public class Address implements Serializable {

   @Id
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "city")
   private String city;

   /* You can use @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn instead of the @MapsId here.
      See the Example 153. Derived identifier @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
      from the hibernate documentation.
   */
   @OneToOne
   @MapsId
   @JoinColumn(name = "id")
   private User user;

   // ...
}
```

and then save user in the following way:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/saveUser")
public String getJpa () {

   User user = new User();
   user.setName("Michael Joseph Jackson");

   Address address = new Address();
   address.setCity("Los Angeles");

   // make both sides of the bidirectional @OneToOne in-sync
   user.setAddress(address);
   address.setUser(user);

   serviceJpa.saveUser(user);

   return "/saveUser";
}
```

And several notes:

1. Whenever a bidirectional association is formed, the application developer must make sure both sides are in-sync at all times.
2. You should not save your entities separately, you just should use a proper [cascading](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade) on your association.
3. You should not set value for the [generated identifier](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators).
4. When you use `@MapsId` on the `Address.user`, it actually means that the `Address` entity will borrow the identifier from the one-to-one association. So, you should not use `@GeneratedValue` annotation for the `Address.id`.  (See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived))

Comment: This is a very good answer and it works. Thank you so much for your work. I have a small question - please tell me, why didn't you use the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation?

Comment: The `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation is used for the similar purpose as the `@MapsId` annotation (see the last link from my answer). But if I correctly understand your intention you want to use generated identifier here.

Comment: How do I delete an address without touching the user?

In this example, I cannot delete "Address".

It is not removed.

How to delete an address without touching the user?

Comment: You can not do it. This is a price for this: *I want to create a common primary key for the User and Address table*. You can create a separate field in the user table that will be a [FK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) (with ON DELETE SET NULL) to the address table. In this case you will be able to remove address record and all FK's related to this address will be set to NULL

Comment: It can be done. I have already done. It was enough to specify orphanRemoval = true.

Thank you very much for your help. In fact, you put me on the right track and opened my eyes.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the  `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` on id field in address entity as it is a foreign key of user entity, it should not be auto incremented.
EDIT:Try by adding these lines

```
 public String getJpa () {

            User user = new User();
            user.setId(1L);
            user.setName("Michael Joseph Jackson");
            Address address = new Address();
            address.setId(1L);
            address.setCity("Los Angeles");
            user.setActivated(address);
            serviceJpa.saveUser(user);
             return "/saveUser";
        }
```

Comment: It won't help. Even if you specify auto.

Comment: Dont specify any startegy for generation of that column because it is a foreign key ,it takes the value from user primary key.(remove all that line)

Comment: I tried to do as you indicated, the error disappeared but the address is not saved. Therefore, this solution does not solve the problem.