# OneToOne CascadeType in spring data jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I use **`OneToOne`** in the **`spring data JPA`** and I want to delete a record from the **`Address`** table without touching the user. But I can't.

If I remove **`User`**, in this case **`Address`** is removed, that's good.

But how can you delete an **`Address`** without touching the **`User`**?

**https://github.com/myTestPercon/TestCascade**

**User.Java**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user", schema = "testCascade")
    public class User implements Serializable {


        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;


        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;


        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Address address;


        // Getter and Setter ...


    }
```

**Address.java**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "address", schema = "testCascade")
    public class Address implements Serializable {


        @Id
        private Long id;


        @Column(name = "city")
        private String city;


        @OneToOne
        @MapsId
        @JoinColumn(name = "id")
        private User user;


        // Getter and Setter ...


    }
```

**DeleteController.java**

```
    @Controller
    public class DeleteController {


        @Autowired
        ServiceJpa serviceJpa;


        @GetMapping(value = "/deleteAddressById")
        public String deleteAddressById () {


            serviceJpa.deleteAddressById(4L);
            return "redirect:/home";


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this problem, you need to read the hibernate [Documentation Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one) **`Example 162`**, **`Example 163`**, **`Example 164`**.

And also I recommend to look at this is [Using @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation in spring data jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66984352/using-primarykeyjoincolumn-annotation-in-spring-data-jpa)

**This helped me in solving this problem.**

And also you need to specify the parameter **`orphanRemoval = true`**

**User.java**

```
    @Entity(name = "User")
    @Table(name = "user", schema = "testother")
    public class User implements Serializable {


        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        private Address address;



        public void addAddress(Address address) {
            address.setUser( this );
            this.address = address;
        }

        public void removeAddress() {
            if ( address != null ) {
                address.setUser( null );
                this.address = null;
            }
        }

        // Getter and Setter
    }
```

**Address.java**

```
    @Entity(name = "Address")
    @Table(name = "address", schema = "testother")
    public class Address implements Serializable {


        @Id
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "city")
        private String city;


        @OneToOne
        @MapsId
        @JoinColumn(name = "id")
        private User user;

        // Getter and Setter
    }
```

**DeleteController .java**

```
    @Controller
    public class DeleteController {

        @Autowired
        ServiceJpa serviceJpa;
        
        @GetMapping(value = "/deleteUser")
        public String deleteUser () {

            User user = serviceJpa.findUserById(2L).get();
            
            user.removeAddress();
            serviceJpa.saveUser(user);
            
            return "/deleteUser";
        }

    }
```

**Or make a custom SQL query.**

```
    @Repository
    public interface DeleteAddress extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {

        @Modifying
        @Query("delete from Address b where b.id=:id")
        void deleteBooks(@Param("id") Long id);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You got  your mapping wrong thats all is the problem .

try the below and see

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "testCascade")
public class User implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;


    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="foriegn key column in user table for address example.. address_id")
    private Address address;


    // Getter and Setter ...


}
```

Address.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address", schema = "testCascade")
public class Address implements Serializable {


    @Id
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    //name of the address variable in your user class
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="address", 
        cascade={CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private User user;


    // Getter and Setter ...


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Address {

   @Id
    private Long id;      

    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User user;
  }
```

Rename `@JoinColumn(name = "id")` to `@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")`

You can't say that the column that will point to user will be the id of the Address

Comment: @OneToOne creates an extra column that points to the other table as foreign key. So you hava said that Address Table will have that extra column. And you name that extra column id. Id must be a foreign key that points to user. So id will have values of user Id. But you already have a column in that table with name id that has the address Id. Hope you see what is messed up here

Comment: I need a generic identifier. Exactly as I have indicated. I just want to remove the address without touching the user. If I go into the MySQL database and delete the address, the address is deleted and the user is not affected. I also want to delete the address without touching the user.

Comment: You have misconfigured your JPA and that is the reason why the user get's accidentally deleted. Change what I said and also search `JoinColumn` and read to see how it works. You will then understand what I have already explained

Comment: I did exactly as you said. The situation has not changed.

  @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "id")
     private Long id;

     @Column(name = "name")
     private String name;

     @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // ALL
     private Address address;

Comment: @zvzvzxvzxv what is your address class now?

Comment: If I delete ("cascade") then an error message appears - object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : org.example.model.User.address -> org.example.model.Address

Comment: @zvzvzxvzxv leave the cascade on User Class. What is your Address Class now?

Comment: @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "users_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private User user;

Comment: https://github.com/myTestPercon/DeleteCron/tree/master/src/main/java/org/example/controller

Comment: on  ServiceJpa call the default method of jpa repository `public void deleteAddressById(Long id) {
        deleteAddress.deleteById(id);
    }`

Comment: Nothing has changed, everything is the same. The problem remains relevant.

Comment: Generate `equals` and `hashCode` on both Address and User and make those methods consider only id field of current class. Also check your DB schema and see if it matches with your entities

Comment: I did as you said. Nothing changed. The problem remains relevant. Image added, see above.

Comment: I suspect that because of your wrong initial configurations your schema has hold a trigger to delete also a User when Address is removed. In that case I would drop the schema if possible and create it again or let JPA create it